# cancel download jsonLoader & ImageUtils.loadTexture

Tags: three.js

How to cancel the download of an object or texture?

```
THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(...

jsonLoader.load(...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, it's not built in.

You could edit the [XHRLoader](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/XHRLoader) class (or create your own) to make the `load()` function to return the `XMLHttpRequest` [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/1769fbfc6c994b51a54c15a5c096855fd3cb8a1a/src/loaders/XHRLoader.js#L66-L69). This would allow you to call its `abort()` function.